# Flutter Firebase Remote Config Fetch JSON as Map

Tags: flutter, firebase-remote-config

In Firebase Remote Config I have a valid json field named `test`:

```json
{
    "title": "Hello, World!"
}
```

In the application I call
`jsonDecode(config.getString('test'))` and it does not work because `config.getString('test')` spits out:

```
{title=Hello, World!}
```

I tried all possible methods on the config:

```
jsonDecode(config.getAll()['test'].asString());
```

and

```
jsonDecode(config.getValue('test').asString())
```

The app crashes since that is not valid JSON.

Comment: jsonDecode(config.getString('test'))["data"]["title"]

Comment: Nope, `jsonDecode` throws an exception because `getString` returns that strange Kotlin-like format

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So the remote config value was fine, but in the app I had made wrong default value for `test` and it got fetched:

```dart
const defaultValue = {
    "title": "Hello, World!",
}
```

```dart
config.setDefaults({
    'test': defaultValue,
});
```

And it should have been:

```dart
config.setDefaults({
    'test': json.encode(defaultValue),
});
```

I thought it was Remote Config's fault

Answer (score 3):

Say this is your `RemoteConfig` map:

```
dummy
  {
    "foo": true,
    "bar": 100
  }
```

This is how you can retrieve the values:

```dart
var rawData = remoteConfig.getAll()['dummy'];
var map = jsonDecode(rawData?.asString() ?? yourDefaultValues);
bool foo = map['foo']; // true
int bar = map['bar']; // 100
```